# Why we can create an ActiveX in IE to automate Outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook, activex

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
function SendMail(to,body,sub)
{
    var theApp    
    var theMailItem      
    var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application")
    var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0)
        
     theMailItem.to = to
     theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
     theMailItem.Body = (msg);

     //theMailItem.display()
     theMailItem.send()
 
}
```

However, I would like to why we can create an ActiveX for the Outlook and what's the relationship between them.

If we can create an ActiveX to automate the Outlook, can we embed the Outlook in the web page?

Any explanation is appreciate.

Comment: The Send method is unsafe and Outlook may trigger security prompts. Read more about that in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) article. So, I'd suggest considering another way for sending emails from web pages. For example, you may user the server-side code (ASP.NET) where you can use System.Net namespace classes. See [Outlook.Application ActiveX - send() sometimes hangs long with hourglass turning and eventually fails](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afc0115b-a8a2-4bf7-86fa-23c6b1fddd01/outlookapplica

Comment: I would to know why it could work for the code above. However, thanks for your suggestion anyway